# At this time should I use plural or singular verb?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Is the following sentence correct?

"Each of our products are guaranteed"

I'm assuming it's correct since the phrase "each of them" is plural

Comment: You've basically just answered your own question.  I'm voting to close this because it doesn't sound like you tried to do any research before asking this.

Comment: "Each of them" is *singular*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Each' with plural or singular verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12387/each-with-plural-or-singular-verb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, "each" is singular.  The prepositional phrase "of them" has no effect on number.

***Each of our products is guaranteed*** is correct, as is ***All of our products are guaranteed.***

In either case, you stand behind your products.

Comment: ...unless you're selling manure-spreaders.

Comment: If your answer is correct how do you explain the sentence "each of them is good" to be correct? I strongly think that the phrase "each of them are good" is correct

Comment: No, Manuel.  "Each of them is good" is still correct.  The prepositional phrase is ignored.  Each is; all are.

Comment: Ok then I thought it sounded weird but I now see it's good. thank you all

Comment: Ok then I thought it sounded weird but I now see it's good. thank you all

Comment: @Rob_ster I have marked your answer as accepted. Thank you very much and please accept my apologies I know I sounded kind of rude.